# Entityframework RC1 - MetadataItem.Annotations made internal - alternatives?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have been using the following method in EF Beta1 to get a List of PropertyInfos, which are referencing a given type:

```cs
public static List<PropertyInfo> GetReferencingAssociations(Type entityType, ObjectContext objectContext)
        {
            var result = (from edmType in objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace)
                          from navigationProperty in edmType.NavigationProperties
                          let propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)navigationProperty.Annotations.Single(y => y.Name == "ClrPropertyInfo").Value
                          where propertyInfo.PropertyType == entityType
                          select propertyInfo).ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

However in the recently released RC1 ([see](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/08/21/ef6-release-candidate-available.aspx)) the **Annotations**-Property of System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataItem has been made internal.

My quick workaround is to use reflection to access the internal property, but I am wondering if there is any other solution to get the PropertyInfo of the given NavigationProperty without the reflection hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An annotation is represented internally by a `MetadataProperty` instance. You should be able to retrieve an annotation from the `MetadataItem.MetadataProperties` collection. An annotation can be added/removed using the `MetadataItem.AddAnnotation` and respectively `MetadataItem.RemoveAnnotation`.